# Example from NetworkX documentation gets an error (all_pairs_shortest_path)

Tags: python, networkx

I tried to copy and paste an example from NetworkX package documentation. 
This is the example:

```
>>>G = nx.path_graph(5)
>>> path = nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G)
>>> print(path[0][4])
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Unfortunately, instead of the expected output, I get the following error message:

```
'generator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation and tell us what version of networkx you are running?  Almost certainly this is a case that the documentation you are reading is for a different version from what you are using.

Comment: I found the example here: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path.html

I just downloaded and updated NetworkX, so it's the most recent one.

Comment: It is working for me (using Python 3.6.1 and networkx=1.11)

Comment: The most recent version is 2.1. [Documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.1/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.unweighted.all_pairs_shortest_path.html?highlight=all_pairs_shortest_path#networkx-algorithms-shortest-paths-unweighted-all-pairs-shortest-path) for `all_pairs_shortest_path` changed since 1.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your error is due to the fact that in Python 2.x many of the methods that used to return dicts now return generators.  Among them is `all_pairs_shortest_path`.  You're using this new version of networkx, but looking at an out-of-date tutorial. 
 So the error message you saw comes from the fact that you have a generator `path` and you're trying to access `path[0]`, which doesn't make sense to Python.  The easiest fix here is to simply follow the answer provided by Walter and say

```
path = dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G))
```

In general, when using code that was written for networkx 1.x, but you are using version 2.x, you should consult the [migration guide](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/migration_guide_from_1.x_to_2.0.html) (though in your case it's not particularly useful).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like path is a generator: convert it into a dictionary and it works:

```
path = dict(nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G))
```